# C# Forms App Localization

Tags: c#, localization

I have modified my question after the comment which refers to article.

I have a c# Win forms app which contains some forms and dialog boxes/message boxes for user interaction.
I want to localize it to a set of languages.

- Most forms are created through the forms designer and the text/strings are set via the properties
- Strings for message boxes and other runtime messages come from the code.

I have read the article here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx

Which points to 2 approaches,

- First is to have Visual Studio create resouece files for you - this is done for forms designer gernerated code
- The second is to manually add resource files and access them code using GetString("strMessage") method

The problem I have in my mind is for desingner generated code I have to use first approch in which VS will create resource files by itself.
To localize my run time messages and mssage boxes I have to use the second approach which means I have to manually add resource files.

I will end up in two sets of resources files for each language. Can I not use just one method and have both form of strings localized in one place ?

Thanks,

Comment: -1/close: Using basic [search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+Forms+App+Localization) immediately gives you correct [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Please read and come back with specific questions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I had read that article before. I have now updated my question to be more specific thanks

Comment: I would look into Satellite Assemblies.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11036/Satellite-Assembly-Multi-Languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't (easily) have your cake and eat it too. It's just how MSFT designed things. You can't add message strings to the code-behind ".resx" files generated by the VS forms designer since those ".resx" files will be re-generated by VS any time you make changes to them (overwriting your message strings). VS even warns you about this if you try to add your own resources to these files (using the ".resx" editor in VS). And the converse isn't true either, i.e., you can't add the code-behind ".resx" resources to your manually created ".resx" files (without enormous difficulties). The situation really isn't that bad though. It's been done for years this way and it works. While I would personally prefer a central repository for all resources, every system has its pros and cons. BTW, you should use "strongly typed" resources for your message strings and any other resources in your ".resx" files (the ones you manually add yourself). Don't use "GetString()" IOW (or whatever other function you might find). Strongly typed resources are much easier. Google for the details and after learning how to use them (not hard), also search for the Strongly Typed Resource Generator by Dmytro Kryvko (a very useful tool for VS that improves things even more).

Comment: Here is a link to the Strongly Typed Resource Generator mentioned above: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13830/Extended-Strongly-Typed-Resource-Generator

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you using a combination of both techniques. Go through step 1 to create all of the language resource files, and then add your own strings to those files.